# SQL statement having in which where clause have multiple values

Tags: c#, sql

I want to fill a `ComboBox` from database but I want two conditions of same column
table column `Group` contain four different values (`rawmaterial`, `formula`, `packing` , `Chemical`).

I want to select item names of group formula and packing

I am using the following query, but it's not working:

```
Select itemName from rawMaterial where Group = 'rawmaterial' , 'Packing'
```

Comment: Are you looking for in('rawmaterial' , 'Packing')? Please, do not say things like want help from you, it sounds a little abrupt.

Comment: looking to select (Formula, packing)

Comment: Use the IN keyword. Raging Bull has also put this in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives:

1. Using `OR`:

   ```
   Select itemName from rawMaterial where Group = 'rawmaterial' OR Group= 'Packing'
   ```
2. Using `IN`:

   ```
   Select itemName from rawMaterial where Group IN ('rawmaterial' , 'Packing')
   ```